# Read XML node from certain element forward?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, linq, linq-to-xml

I know there are a bunch of ways of doing this, but I'm looking for the easiest way of doing it without having to use a streamreader or something more manual that will force me to loop through the whole file and compare endless strings. A possibility would be to use a streamreader to find a specific text, and then use some XML library to retrieve the node.

Here's my XML. This is what I would need to do:

1) find the first instance of tag **npid** with text *Text to Find*

2) Extract the node **NodeToExtract** and store it in some data object. There are several nodes called **NodeToExtract** but I just want the first one after the initial search of text *Text to Find*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<mdc>
    <ne>
    <neun>ADB</neun>
    <nn>SubNetwork=Context</nn>
    <nw>R33</nw>    
    <mi>
    <nut>20140101</nut>
    <hq>000</hq>
    <nw>
    <npid>Text to Find</npid>
    <r>0</r>
    </nw>
    </mi>
    </ne>
    <ofid>
    <ofun>ABC</ofun>
    <ofdn>Blah</ofdn>
    <ofsw>18R</ofsw>
    </ofid>
    <NodeToExtract>
    <mts>More Blah</mts>
    <gp>000</gp>
    <mu>Value1</mu>
    <mu>Value2</mu>
    <mu>Value3</mu>
    <mu>Value4</mu>
    <mu>Value5</mu>
    <nw>
    <npid>ABC1221</npid>
    <r>99</r>
    <r>0</r>
    <r>0</r>
    <r>0</r>
    <r>0</r>
    </nw>
    <nw>
    <npid>ABC1222</npid>
    <r>99</r>
    <r>0</r>
    <r>0</r>
    <r>0</r>
    <r>0</r>
    </nw>
    <nw>
    <npid>ABC1223</npid>
    <r>99</r>
    <r>0</r>
    <r>0</r>
    <r>0</r>
    <r>0</r>
    </nw>
    </NodeToExtract>
</mdc>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your XML is malformed and there is no attribute `Text to Find` in it.

Comment: The ReadSubTree method is the one you want, I think...

Comment: I just knew someone was going to reply with "Your XML is malformed". To clear up any confusion, the XML file is 400K; I can't post the whole file, now can I? As I mentioned in the post, of the 14,500 lines, this chunk is what interests me most. And finally, so I mis-wrote: there's a tag called npid with text "Text to Find". Are you seeing it now?

Comment: In order to analyze the structure of your XML, one needs at least `working` & `well-formed` XML fragment. Please post a `well-formed` minimum sample.

Comment: I've added a well-formed XML chunk.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `NodeToExtract`?

Comment: There's a node called NodeToExtract. I want to retrieve the whole element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out (assuming you mean `mi` elements by saying `NodeToExtract`):

```
    XElement doc = XElement.Parse(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1""?><mdc><ne><neun>ADB</neun><nn>SubNetwork=Context</nn><nw>R33</nw><mi><nut>20140101</nut><hq>000</hq><nw><npid>Text to Find</npid><r>0</r></nw></mi></ne><ofid><ofun>ABC</ofun><ofdn>Blah</ofdn><ofsw>18R</ofsw></ofid><mi><mts>More Blah</mts><gp>000</gp><mu>Value1</mu><mu>Value2</mu><mu>Value3</mu><mu>Value4</mu><mu>Value5</mu><nw><npid>ABC1221</npid><r>99</r><r>0</r><r>0</r><r>0</r><r>0</r></nw><nw><npid>ABC1222</npid><r>99</r><r>0</r><r>0</r><r>0</r><r>0</r></nw><nw><npid>ABC1223</npid><r>99</r><r>0</r><r>0</r><r>0</r><r>0</r></nw></mi></mdc>");
    IEnumerable<XElement> query1 = doc.Descendants("npid").Where(c => c.Value == "Text to Find").Ancestors("mi");
    IEnumerable<XElement> query2 = query1.First().Parent.ElementsAfterSelf("mi");
    dynamic resut_node = new XElement("result");
    resut_node.Add(query1.First());
    resut_node.Add(query2.First());
    Console.Write(resut_node.ToString());
```

## UPDATE

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1""?>
                                                <mdc>
                                                    <ne>
                                                        <neun>ADB</neun>
                                                        <nn>SubNetwork=Context</nn>
                                                        <nw>R33</nw>
                                                        <mi>
                                                            <nut>20140101</nut>
                                                            <hq>000</hq>
                                                            <nw>
                                                                <npid>Text to Find</npid>
                                                                <r>0</r>
                                                            </nw>
                                                        </mi>
                                                    </ne>
                                                    <ofid>
                                                        <ofun>ABC</ofun>
                                                        <ofdn>Blah</ofdn>
                                                        <ofsw>18R</ofsw>
                                                    </ofid>
                                                    <NodeToExtract>
                                                        <mts>More Blah</mts>
                                                        <gp>000</gp>
                                                        <mu>Value1</mu>
                                                        <mu>Value2</mu>
                                                        <mu>Value3</mu>
                                                        <mu>Value4</mu>
                                                        <mu>Value5</mu>
                                                        <nw>
                                                            <npid>ABC1221</npid>
                                                            <r>99</r>
                                                            <r>0</r>
                                                            <r>0</r>
                                                            <r>0</r>
                                                            <r>0</r>
                                                        </nw>
                                                        <nw>
                                                            <npid>ABC1222</npid>
                                                            <r>99</r>
                                                            <r>0</r>
                                                            <r>0</r>
                                                            <r>0</r>
                                                            <r>0</r>
                                                        </nw>
                                                        <nw>
                                                            <npid>ABC1223</npid>
                                                            <r>99</r>
                                                            <r>0</r>
                                                            <r>0</r>
                                                            <r>0</r>
                                                            <r>0</r>
                                                        </nw>
                                                    </NodeToExtract>
                                                </mdc>");

            IEnumerable<XElement> query1 = doc.Descendants("npid").Where(c => c.Value == "Text to Find").Ancestors("mi");
            IEnumerable<XElement> query2 = query1.First().Parent.ElementsAfterSelf("NodeToExtract");

            Console.Write(query2.First().ToString());
```

Comment: Works very well. One last thing, would you know how to move query2.First() into a dataset or datatable? Thanks.

Comment: I ended up using this to copy the resulting string to a dataset:

`StringReader stream = null;
XmlTextReader reader = null;
DataSet xmlDS = new DataSet();
stream = new StringReader(xml);
reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
xmlDS.ReadXml(reader);`

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is that there is no way to do this without brute force. One can extract the node in question and then load it into an xmldocument,

for example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string buffer = " blah blah blah " +
            "<nw>" +
            "<npid>Text to Find</npid>" +
            "<r>0</r>" +
            "</nw>" +
            "</mi>" +
            "</ne>" +
            "<ne>" +
            "<ofid>" +
            "<ofun>ABC</ofun>" +
            "<ofdn>Blah</ofdn>" +
            "<ofsw>18R</ofsw>" +
            "</ofid>" +
            "<mi>" +
            "<mts>Good stuff</mts>" +
            "<gp>000</gp>" +
            "<mu>Value1</mu>" +
            "<mu>Value2</mu>" +
            "<mu>Value3</mu>" +
            "<mu>Value4</mu>" +
            "<mu>Value5</mu>" +
            "<nw>" +
            "<npid>ABC1221</npid>" +
            "<r>99</r>" +
            "<r>0</r>" +
            "<r>0</r>" +
            "<r>0</r>" +
            "<r>0</r>" +
            "</nw>" +
            "<nw>" +
            "<npid>ABC1222</npid>" +
            "<r>99</r>" +
            "<r>0</r>" +
            "<r>0</r>" +
            "<r>0</r>" +
            "<r>0</r>" +
            "</nw>" +
            "<nw>" +
            "<npid>ABC1223</npid>" +
            "<r>99</r>" +
            "<r>0</r>" +
            "<r>0</r>" +
            "<r>0</r>" +
            "<r>0</r>" +
            "</nw>" +
            "</mi> blah blah blah";

        int indexOf_Text = buffer.IndexOf( "Text to Find" );

        XmlDocument nextMiNode = ExtractNode( indexOf_Text, buffer );

        // now traverse the node as you please
        foreach ( XmlNode node in nextMiNode.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes )
        {
            if ( node.Name == "mts" )
            {
                // Good stuff ?
                if ( node.InnerText == "Good stuff" )
                    Console.WriteLine( node.InnerText );
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static XmlDocument ExtractNode(int indexOf_Text, string buffer)
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        StringBuilder sbNode = new StringBuilder();
        sbNode.Append( "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" );
        bool inNode = false;
        for ( int i = indexOf_Text; i < buffer.Length - 1; i++ )
        {
            // find the first "<mi>" tag ..
            if ( !inNode &&
                ( buffer[i] == '<' &&
                  i + 3 < buffer.Length - 1 &&
                  buffer[i + 1] == 'm' &&
                  buffer[i + 2] == 'i' &&
                  buffer[i + 3] == '>' ) )
                inNode = true;

            if ( inNode ) // capture it
                sbNode.Append( buffer[i] );

            // find the next "<mi/>" ending tag (only if we found the begining tag : inNode=true)
            if ( inNode &&
                ( buffer[i] == '>' &&
                  i - 4 >= indexOf_Text &&
                  buffer[i - 1] == 'i' &&
                  buffer[i - 2] == 'm' &&
                  buffer[i - 3] == '/' &&
                  buffer[i - 4] == '<' ) )
            {
                break; // we are done
            }
        }
        xDoc.LoadXml( sbNode.ToString() );
        return xDoc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I'd be parsing it manually, which is exactly what I want to avoid.